# How to deploy Flask with nginx, gunicorn, and supervisord?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I have managed to deploy a simple Flask app based on the nice tutorial [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/).

As you will see, the project has the following structure:

```
|___README.md
|___fabfile.py
|___config
| |___post-receive
| |___flask_project.conf
| |___flask_project
|___flask_project
| |___static
| | |___index.html
| |___app.py
|___requirements.txt
```

My problem is that, when I change the structure a little bit and deploy again, everything stops working and the `nginx` throws the following error: `502 Bad Gateway`. Note that, I am supposed to have made the correct changes in corresponding files before deployment (but apparently, this is not the case here).

So, I would really appreciate it if you could help me find all necessary changes according to the following (new) structure so as to make my project work again!

```
|___web
| |___README.md
| |___TODO.md
| |___run.py
| |___application
|___deployment
| |___README.md
| |___web
| |___web.conf
| |___TODO.md
| |___post-receive
| |___fabfile.py
| |___requirements.txt
```

Comment: Does your python skript run in your new structure? Does it find all needed modules?

Comment: Yes, it does run in the new structure, that's the point anyway. I guess it does find all the modules because I am able to run it locally.